# Spring joint with relative connected anchor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a plunger for a pinball table. It's basically a cube with a rigidbody and spring joint attached. When a particular key is pressed, i'm trying to add some z value to the spring's connectedAnchor to move the cube and when the key is no longer pressed, then the connectedAnchor returns to its original position.

The problem is that the connectedAnchor manipulation happens in worldspace, and since my table is rotated, moving the cube along the z axis is not correct. Essentially what I'm looking for is a way to effect the connected anchor, but to use the axes local to the cube's transform and not the worldspace axes.

To get the original connectedAnchor, I check "auto configure" and then uncheck it before I do manipulations. The unity docs for the [Joint.connectedAnchor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-connectedAnchor.html) say this should work, but it doesn't.

```
Here's my script:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlungerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float movement_increment_z;

    public float max_movement_z;

    private SpringJoint spring;
    private Vector3 orig_anchor;

    private void Start() {
        spring = GetComponent<SpringJoint>();
        if (!spring) { throw new System.Exception("spring joint is needed"); };
        orig_anchor = spring.connectedAnchor;
    }

    public void processPlungerInput (bool isKeyPressed) {
        Debug.Log(orig_anchor);
        if (isKeyPressed) {
            if (spring.connectedAnchor.z < max_movement_z) {
                spring.connectedAnchor += new Vector3(0,0,movement_increment_z);
            } else {
                spring.connectedAnchor = orig_anchor;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The rigidbody is constrained on everything except z axis movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking a slightly different approach. Rather than changing the connected anchor of the spring, I kept that constant and set the connected body to a statically positioned origin transform.

When the key is pressed, I temporarily set the spring to 0 and then change the position of the plunger object. When the key is not pressed I set the spring to a high value so that it snaps back to the anchor point.

To deal with the question of constraints, instead of using the options on the rigidbody inspector (which only locks position on the worldspace axes) I used a script which sets the rotation and x/y position to the original values each frame.

The script looks like this now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlungerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float movement_increment_z;

    public float max_movement_z;
    public float spring_power;

    private SpringJoint spring;
    private Vector3 orig_anchor;
    private Quaternion orig_rotation;
    private float orig_pos_x, orig_pos_y;

    private void Start() {
        spring = GetComponent<SpringJoint>();
        if (!spring) { throw new System.Exception("spring joint is needed"); };
        orig_anchor = spring.connectedAnchor;
        orig_rotation = transform.localRotation;
        orig_pos_y = transform.localPosition.y;
        orig_pos_x = transform.localPosition.x;
    }

    public void processPlungerInput (bool isKeyPressed) {
        if (isKeyPressed) {
            spring.spring = 0;
            if (transform.localPosition.z < max_movement_z) {
                transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0,0,movement_increment_z);
            }
        } else {
            spring.spring = spring_power;
        }
    }

    // preserve only z axis movement and no rotation at all.
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        transform.localRotation = orig_rotation;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(orig_pos_x, orig_pos_y, transform.localPosition.z);
    }

}
```